# Are React / JSX Generated HTML Elements Invisible to Google Web Crawlers?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, templates, components

I recently read an article about how HTML elements created with JavaScript are not picked up by the Googlebot / Google crawlers. The reason being, in its most simple form, the HTML the GoogleBot picks up is everything that is shown when you do View Page Source.

I'm about to start learning React, one of the reasons for this being that you can create template files and components, so common features such as headers and footers etc and be duplicated easily to keep your code DRY.

It worries me though that if I was to do this, the React / JSX generated HTML would effectively not be tracked by web crawlers, thus making it essentially invisible, which would create a large number of potential negatives, not least, inferior SEO.

My question therefore is - does HTML generated with React behave in the same way HTML generated with vanilla JavaScript does? I'm assuming it must do, but I can't find any proper answers to this when googling?

Many thanks,

Emily.

Comment: Not strictly true https://medium.freecodecamp.org/seo-vs-react-is-it-neccessary-to-render-react-pages-in-the-backend-74ce5015c0c9

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs is an isomorphic or Universal or environment agnostic.

You can build client side application and also server side applications.

As you are already aware of client side of it. Now you checkout the server side implementation in the below tutorial
https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app

you can also checkout the following boilerplates which provide SSR :
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

https://github.com/TimoRuetten/react-ssr-boilerplate